# How can I execute a Junit test?

Tags: java, testing, junit, jhipster

I generated part of this test with the generator of controllers of jhipster, with the command: jhipster generate-controller NAME-CONTROLLER
but I don't know how can I try a jnit test, the code that I have is:

```
     * Test class for the NotificationResource REST controller.
 *
 * @see NotificationResource
 */
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApp.class)
public class NotificationResourceIT {

    private MockMvc restMockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

        NotificationResource notificationResource = new NotificationResource();
        restMockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(notificationResource)
            .build();
    }

    public static String asJsonString(final Object obj) {
        try {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Test postNotification
     */
    @Test
    public void testPostNotification() throws Exception {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("02.11.2019",formatter);
        restMockMvc.perform(post("/api/notification/post-notification")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(asJsonString(date))
                )
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

I'am using IDE Eclipse, and I select the file and do clic in Run as Junit, and this give me the next message:

[image]

and in console appear the next:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/commons/PreconditionViolationException
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.createTest(JUnit5TestLoader.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit5TestLoader.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:525)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.commons.PreconditionViolationException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 7 more
```

I need help for try this test, I will apreciate much your help

Comment: Are you able to run the tests from command line using maven or gradle? I suspect a problem of configuration in your Eclipse project

Answer (score 3):

Like the others say, you need a test runner.

Since you have a `@SpringBootTest`, you need a `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`.

If you use JUnit5, you use `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing your code, aren't you missing the ***Test Runner***? It's a class with the Main function that you call the tests you want to run. You can find an example in the TutorialsPoint website: [JUnit Executing Tests](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_executing_tests.htm).

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding @RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class) annotation to your class

Answer (score 0):

```
if Gradle:  

      dependencies {
        testImplementation('org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.6.1')
        testCompile group: 'org.junit.vintage', name: 'junit-vintage-engine', version: '5.6.1'
 // your Mock lib...
      }
    repositories {  jcenter() }
    plugins {
         id 'java-library'
         id 'war'// optional 
         id 'eclipse' // optional, for Eclipse project
      }
    test { useJUnitPlatform() }
```